# apply number format to pandas.io.formats.style.Styler to export to excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem
I want to export a dataframe to excel, before doing this, I apply some formats, which generates a pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.

when I try to make a column numeric format it doesn't work for me.

It only works with DataFrames but not pandas.io.formats.style.Styler

Is there any solution?

dtCruzado is the dataframe

```
diferenciaPermitida=Decimal('0.02')
styleNoEncontrado =lambda x: ['background-color: %s' % 'red' if x=="No Encontrado" else '' for x in dtCruzado.Estado_Cruce]

dt=dtCruzado.style\
    .apply(styleNoEncontrado, axis=0)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path+"\\Cruce_"+today.strftime("%d-%B-%Y")+".xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        datetime_format='mmm d yyyy',
                        date_format='mmmm dd yyyy')





formatNumeric = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
worksheet.set_column('O:O', 14, formatNumeric)
worksheet.set_column('P:P', 14, formatNumeric)



# Adjust the column width.




# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```